# What do you call the side of a building that is neither the near side nor the far side?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, compound-adjectives

What do you call the side of a building that is neither the near side nor the far side?

A friend suggested *adjacent*. I think that fits, but is there a way to distinguish between adjacent faces of a building when you are closer to one of them, like *near adjacent* or something similar?

The sentence I currently have is:

> The sounds of conversation brought her attention to the adjacent side of the building where fellow members of the dojo were making their way out towards whatever transportation would bring them home.

Comment: How about "The sounds of the conversation led her around the near (or *nearby*) corner of the building, where fellow..."

Comment: Umm...  The side side?

Comment: “The adjacent side of the building” is ok; but the phrase  “brought her attention” is not.   “Drew her attention” or “attracted her attention” would be ok.

Comment: The question is required within the body, even if mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When facing a specific side of a building, the sides could be called: near side, left side, far side, right side.

If this was placed into your sentence, it could become:

> The sounds of conversation brought her attention to the [**left** or
>   **right**] side of the building where fellow members of the dojo were
>   making their way out towards whatever transportation would bring them
>   home.

Comment: Or just simply "to the side of the building where..."

Comment: I'd go with this unless it was really necessary to specify _which_ side, but you need a comma after 'building' if you don't want 'where fellow members of the dojo were making their way out ...' to be a defining relative clause.

Comment: Would you consider left side and right side to be in relation to the side of the building you are facing, or to the front of the building?

Comment: @Susanoh13 -  I would consider the left and right side to be in relation to the side of the building one is facing. So left and right side from the viewer's perspective.